# How to extend Doctrine2 by PostgreSQL ~ operator? (Not a custom function)

Tags: postgresql, doctrine-orm, abstract-syntax-tree, lexer

I use Symfony and Doctrine with a PostgreSQL backend and I would like to use the PostgreSQL `~` operator to get the whole power of POSIX regular expression instead of the restricted `LIKE`.

I would like to write something like this

```php
entityManager->createQuery(
        'SELECT e FROM MyBundle:Entity e WHERE e.name ~ :name'
    )->setParameters(
        array( "name" => "some regex here" )
    )->getResult();
```

I already found [this example](http://punkave.com/window/2012/07/24/for-the-php-crowd-adding-custom-functions-to-doctrine-2-dql) and the [official documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#adding-your-own-functions-to-the-dql-language). However they only cope with *custom functions*. But I do not need a function (or term) that evaluates to some value but a *custom predicate*.
Even if I created a custom DQL function – say `REGEXP` – with two parameters that translated to `~` at the SQL level, then the DQL parser would still expect an operator. Hence, `WHERE REGEXP( a, b )` alone would create an DQL parsing error and `WHERE REGEXP( a, b ) = true` would satisfy the DQL parser but would translate to insane `WHERE a ~ b = TRUE` on the SQL level.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to run the query manually like this:

```
entityManager
  ->getConnection()
  ->prepare("
      SELECT *
      FROM table
      WHERE name ~ :regex_pattern
  ")->execute(array(
    'regex_pattern' => 'REGEX PATTERN'
  ))->fetch();
```